# Binding NSAttributedString and NSTextView

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am trying to follow an example from a book where there is an `NSTextView` in the interface that should be bound to an `NSAttributedString` in the controller class. I have the string in an attribute called text and I bind the text view to the File Owner's `self.text.` As far as I can see, that is what the book tells me to do.

[image: NSAttributed string attribute.]

[image: Binding.]

I get an error, though:

```
class Notes.Document
2019-05-29 11:49:02.433383+0200 Notes[3568:27704580] Cannot create attributed string from object <Notes.Document: 0x600002c30100> of class Notes.Document
```

I am completely clueless about what is happening. I would read this as the binding trying to convert the Document object (so self) to an attributed string, but I don't see how it would get that idea.

Comment: At least a KVO compliant property must be declared `@objc dynamic var text...` and the bound key path is just `text` without `self`.

Comment: That did it, thanks. Neither @objc or dynamic is in the book and since I am just beginning to learn this it was hard to even figure out where to look for a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Swift evolves very fast. The book might be older.

Comment: Yeah, it is from 2017. Lots of deprecated functions but those I can find the replacements for. Something that goes through the interface builder is not so easy :)